# Closing a Window in Qt4

Tags: qt4

I have a `QMainWindow` (called mainWindow) where the user can enter several thigs, like a path to a file etc. Then the user can open another Window (called secondWindow) by clicking on a button, do something there and finally return to the first window.

I open the second window and hide first one like that:

```
secondWindow *sw = new secondWindow;
sw->show();
this->hide(); //hide the mainWindow
```

When the user returns to mainWindow, all things he configured before, like the pathname mentioned above, should still be there. So my question is: How do I close secondWindow and return to mainWindow properly?

**EDIT**: `StatusBars` ans `ToolBars` are used. And yes, I do need two windows (actually I even have more than two).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emit a signal from the closeEvent of secondWindow, and connect this signal to the show() slot of mainWindow.

secondWindow.h:

```
public:
virtual void closeEvent ( QCloseEvent * event )
{
    emit secondWindowClosed();
    QWidget::closeEvent(event);
}
signals:
void secondWindowClosed();
```

mainWindow.cpp:

```
secondWindow *sw = new secondWindow;
connect(sw, SIGNAL(secondWindowClosed()), this, SLOT(show()));
sw->show();
this->hide(); //hide the mainWindow
```

Answer (score 0):

if not using the features of `QMainWindow`, like `QStatusBar` or `QToolbar` for me the best choice would be using `QDialog` and call `QDialog::exec()`.

it will pop up modal, so the user is forced to close the dialog before interacting with the `mainWindow` again.

the other way would be to emit a signal when closing the `secondWindow` and free all resources if needed.
like:

```
void secondWindowClosing(void)//SLOT in mainWindow called by SIGNAL closing() or whatever from secondWindow
{
    secondWindow* wnd = qobject_cast<secondWindow*>(QObject::sender());
    if (!wnd) // if the SLOT was called not using signals/slots (may not be needed)
        return;
    // get your information of the secondWindow 
    wnd->deleteLater(); // deletes wnd, after the application returns to the event loop
    this->show(); // display the mainWindow again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need two windows? I would use a QStackedWidget. One QMainWindow, which gets as central widget a QStackedWidget. In the QStackedWidget your controls for your first and second window.